# Custom Navigationbar in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, ios, navigation, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

Im new to Titanium. I have created the Navigation-bar by following the post

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/drilldown-navigation-with-titanium/

Here I want to customize the Default toolbar and that back button(named as per window).

please guide me friends,
GANESH M

Comment: What's the problem you are facing??

Comment: I cannot go back with custom toolbar.. actually the navigation bar back button is created by default. my need is to change that back button with customizable colour, size etc.

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/127635/problem-with-android-back-button

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on this in the Titanium Docs. If you follow this it should work for you. Note the differences between using Titanium 3.3+ and 3.2- http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Themes